# Is it possible to add a Logmein printer to a Windows virtual machine running on the remote PC?

Tags: vmware-player, logmein

When I remote into my office PC from home, I routinely print to my home printer by selecting it in the printer dialog box. It has "Logmein" appended to the usual printer name.

Now I have a VMware Windows 8 Pro virtual machine running on my office PC.  When I am remoted into my office PC via Logmein, and use the W8P VM, is it possible to print from that VM to my home printer? In Devices and Printers on the W8P VM, I can see my office printers, but not the logmein printer that exists during the remote session.